# Callback never comes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi controller which calls a third party API in asynchronous mode. 
All works ok and now I want to sort the result in a separate action method.
Now, when I call the API, the callback with the result never happens after running "await client.GetAsycn(...)" in the DAL. What am I missing?

This is my **API controller**:

```
    // GET api/lookup
    [ResponseType(typeof(RestaurantModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string outcode)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outcode)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outcode));

        var result = await _repository.GetRestaurantsByOutcode(outcode);

        return Ok(new RestaurantModel()
        {
            Result = result
        });
    }

    // GET api/sorted
    [System.Web.Http.Route("~/api/sorted")]
    public List<Restaurant> GetSorted(string outcode)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outcode)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outcode));

        return _repository.GetSortedRestaurantsByOutcode(outcode);
    }
```

This is my **repository** with a new method to sort the result:

```
public class RestaurantRepository : IRestaurantRepository
{
    private readonly IContext _context;

    public RestaurantRepository(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task<ApiResult> GetRestaurantsByOutcode(string outcode)
    {
        return _context.GetRestaurantsByOutcode(outcode);
    }
    public List<Restaurant> GetSortedRestaurantsByOutcode(string outcode)
    {
        return _context.GetRestaurantsByOutcode(outcode).Result.Restaurants
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

This is my **DAL** to call the third party API:

```
    public async Task<ApiResult> GetRestaurantsByOutcode(string outcode)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            ConfigureHttpClient(client);

            var response = await client.GetAsync(
                $"restaurants?q={WebUtility.UrlEncode(outcode)}");

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode
                ? await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResult>()
                : null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix-match of sometimes you use async/await and other times you don't. Async / await (*can and does by default*) ensures that the call resumes on the calling thread so the context is resulted. You need to allign your code so you make use of the async/await in the whole stack. Otherwise you are creating a deadlock for your self.

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("~/api/sorted")]
// missing async in signature (not good if you are calling it with await in your controller)
public async Task<List<Restaurant>> GetSorted(string outcode)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outcode)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outcode));
    // added await in call
    return await _repository.GetSortedRestaurantsByOutcode(outcode);
}
```

DAL

```
public class RestaurantRepository : IRestaurantRepository
{
    private readonly IContext _context;

    public RestaurantRepository(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // added async and await
    public async Task<ApiResult> GetRestaurantsByOutcode(string outcode)
    {
        return await _context.GetRestaurantsByOutcode(outcode);
    }
    // added async and await
    public async Task<List<Restaurant>> GetSortedRestaurantsByOutcode(string outcode)
    {
        // here you were not using await but then using result even though you were calling into a method marked as async which in turn used an await. this is where you deadlocked but this the fix.
        return (await _context.GetRestaurantsByOutcode(outcode)).Restaurants
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```